# Косить под кого-то

Tags: этимология, жаргон

Есть такое жаргонное (или сленговое?) выражение "косить под кого-то". То есть, стараться быть похожим на кого-то, подражать кому-то. "Она постоянно косит под любимую киногероиню".
Но интересно, почему именно "косить"? Как могло образоваться такое выражение?
Связано это с понятием косьбы или наркоманского косяка?

Answer (score 1):

Наркоманы тут ни при чем. Идиома (назовем так, хотя спорно) возникла в те времена, когда о косяках никто и не слышал.

С косьбой тоже как-то не очень получатся. Можно, конечно, как-то подвести под "косьбу на чужом участке" и подобное, но фантастично, не крестьянское это выражение. Я думаю, что самое понятная версия - это от косить глазами. Помимо очевидной образности (косой - неправильный несовершенный, поддельный), у сильно косящего человека обычно странное выражение лица, запоминается только этот дефект, остальное становится несущественным, его легко принять за другого.

Отсюда же, видимо, откосить - уклониться. Особенно популярно в отношении призыва - косых даже в рекруты не брали, хотя масса других дефектов считались несущественными.

Answer (score 1):

Косить - это устремлять (взгляд, глаза) вбок, в сторону, смотреть искоса. Также можно коситься на своё отражение в зеркале или на стоящих в стороне людей.

Мне кажется, что косить под кого-то (жарг.) - это стараться быть на кого-то похожим, постоянно имея в поле зрения (где-нибудь сбоку) выбранный предмет  и сверяя себя и свое поведение с этим ориентиром, например:

"Галифакс - столица провинции Новая Шотландия и старательно "косит" под свою британскую родственницу. Кругом расхаживают здоровенные мужики в клетчатых юбках и дудят на волынках".

Comment: >постоянно имея в поле зрения  
  
Это не согласуется с практикой применения. 
Вот у меня словарик блатной лексики Кучинского - не шибко авторитетный, но более полного под рукой просто нет. 

Косануть, откосить - уклониться (от работы)
Косить - обсанывать, претворяться больным
Косить под вольтанутого, косить дурку - притворяться сумасшедшим
Косить под гобратого - притворяться непонимающим (непричастным), не сознаваться (=уйти в непонятку); врать особо нагло...

Comment: Косить под дурака - это  притворяться дураком, ориентируясь на него (искоса, боковым зрением), как на образец. Косить дурку (переходный глагол) - изображать дурака. Другое значение у "косануть, откосить" - это уйти в сторону, вбок от чего-либо.